Define DH parametes in python-mbedtls
I'm using python-mbedtls library - https://github.com/Synss/python-mbedtls/tree/master
my goal is to create handshake with different cipher suites,
I've managed to do so with the given server and client files in the library - https://github.com/Synss/python-mbedtls/tree/master/programs
my problem is  - when I use cipher that require DH parameters (DHE) I cant configure it.
I get an error that the DH parameters are not set.
I know how to do that with SSL and how to work with Mbedtls it self in C code.
but my project restriction is to create it in python.
does anyone have any idea how can I define them using this library?

welcome - as it stands there's not enough info to answer unless someone specifically knows about your particular use-case - prob is your q will be off-topic once you clarify (eg. call/s you make and the error/s you're getting) because you're be asking a programming q, sorry! https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
